# async.js swapping variable references after callback?

Tags: node.js, express, async.js

I'm using the following code to insert a row into a database.  After the callback triggering the final async.waterfall function err and result are swapping references.  Before sql_pool.release err is null and results contains the results from the query.  They are passed to the async callback() function and on the other side err is the result set from the query and results is undefined.

I'm certain I'm missing something, but I can't figure out what.

```
exports.addEquipType = function(type, cb){
async.waterfall([
    //Acquire SQL connection from pool
    function(callback){
        sql_pool.acquire(function(err, connection){
            callback(err, connection);
        });
    },
    //Prepare and execute SQL
    function(connection, callback){
        var sql = 'INSERT INTO equip_type VALUES(?,?)';
        var inserts = [null, type];
        sql = mysql.format(sql,inserts);
        connection.query(sql, function(err, results) {
            sql_pool.release(connection);
            callback(err, results);  
        });
    },
    function(err, results) {
        if(!results.insertId){
            cb(err, results);
        }else {
            cb(results.insertId);
        }
}], function (err) {
        cb(err, null);
    }
)
```

};

Answer (score 0):

Ok.  Figured this one out with a bit of trial and error.  It seems I don't need to include err in the parameter list of the next function in the waterfall.  I need to callback with it from the previous function, however.

Updated working code:

```
exports.addEquipType = function(type, cb){
async.waterfall([
    //Acquire SQL connection from pool
    function(callback){
        sql_pool.acquire(function(err, connection){
            callback(err, connection);
        });
    },
    //Prepare and execute SQL
    function(connection, callback){
        var sql = 'INSERT INTO equip_type VALUES(?,?)';
        var inserts = [null, type];
        sql = mysql.format(sql,inserts);
        connection.query(sql, function(err, results) {
            sql_pool.release(connection);
            callback(err, results);  
        });
    },
    function(results) {
        if(!results){
            cb(null);
        }else {
            cb(results);
        }
}], function (err) {
        cb(null);
    }
)
```

};